# Is there a way to count how many times a function mock was called with a certain set of arguments?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, pytest

I have a function for mocking an api call that looks like this:

```
def mocked_api_call(animal = animal, soundtype=soundtype)

    output = make_sound(animal, soundtype)

    return output
```

The goal is to have the mock return a different output the second time it was called with the same set of arguments. For example, I would like the first call to return 'meow', the second time to return 'MEAAAOWWW' and the third call to return 'mew', like so:

```
output = mocked_api_call(animal='cat', soundtype = 'meow')
# outputs 'meow'

output = mocked_api_call(animal='cat', soundtype = 'meow')
# outputs 'MEAAAOWWW'

output = mocked_api_call(animal='cat', soundtype = 'meow')
# outputs 'mew'
```

The patches are used to test a parent function that uses the function that calls the api:

```
def parent_function(**kwargs):
    response = make_sound(animal=animal, soundtype=soundtype)
```

The test function is invoked through a monkeypatch like so:

```
@mock.patch('myscript.api_call', side_effect=mocked_api_call) 
def test_parent_function(*args, **kwargs):
    output = parent_function(**kwargs)
```

But I can't find a way to generate a response that is contingent on how many times the function was called. Is this something you can do with pytest?

Comment: So where do you want to get the output? Should it be random (e.g. where comes 'MEAAAOWWW' from)? Generally, you can probably use `side_effect`, but that depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I would like to have the output be different depending whether its the first time or the second time the function is called.

Comment: Have you looked at [side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect)?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - I have - added more details above. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, the question is what do you need in a single test - different outputs for one specific animal and soundtype?

Comment: Yes - how do you generate a response based on the number of times the function has been called with those specific arguments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213637/discussion-between-mrbean-bremen-and-lespaul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure how your test is going to look, but let's assume you want to have different tests, where the call index is reset in each test. The following may be a bit too generic for you, depending on your needs - you also may just pass the index to `make_sound`, if that is all you need.

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest


class TestSounds:
    indexes = {}
    sounds = {
        ('cat', 'meow'): ('meow', 'MEAAAOWWW', 'mew'),
    }

    @classmethod
    def make_sound(cls, animal, soundtype):
        key = (animal, soundtype)
        if key in cls.sounds:
            index = cls.indexes.setdefault(key, 0)
            sound = cls.sounds[key][index]
            cls.indexes[key] = (index + 1) % len(cls.sounds[key])
            return sound

    # if you need the order not be reset in each test, you can change 
    # the scope to "class"
    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def reset_indexes(self):
        self.__class__.indexes = {}

    def test_parent_function(self, **kwargs):
        with mock.patch('myscript.api_call',
                        side_effect=[self.make_sound(**kwargs),
                                     self.make_sound(**kwargs)]):
            output1 = parent_function(**kwargs)
            output2 = parent_function(**kwargs)
```

Note that this is untested, but it may give you some ideas.